# Wrong url in magento paging

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem regarding paging of the custom module. When i click on the next page the it take the url as  localhost/magento/fme-support/index/index/url/BC/?p=1, but this url doesn't work properly, the correct URL is `localhost/magento/fme-support/category/BC/?p=1`.
Please suggest me how and i change this url.
Thanks.

Comment: which extension are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try making url rewrites off

If it doesn't work there is some issue with your extension you have installed
Check for redirect in your extension

Comment: Check ur extension code where redirect is there
Also check if url rewrite for the category is there in admin

Comment: i solving my problem with the help of str_replace function so thanks for u r comments

Answer (score 0):

The "index" in the URL means you are calling the index controller of the module.

Magento module URLs work like this

http://magento_installation.com/(storeview)/moduleMame/controllerName/functionName/